# How to get old console logs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, console, logging

I am stuck in a kind of situation. My app was working fine a few days ago and it was generating some logs on console (I was testing on simulator).

But now I am having some unknown problem in running my app. I need to see those older console logs. Is there any way to see them?

Answer (score 0):

One word answer, **NO**. You can't get that back.

Comment: You welcome... :) Welcome to SO.. Try to accept answers if it solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

no, if you pressed the "clear log" button in the console window (or from main menu)...